# RestTemplate returns empty JSONObject but works with String

Tags: java, json, resttemplate

When I run

`ResponseEntity<JSONObject> response = queryToRest.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers), JSONObject.class);`

the function returns 200 and an empty body {}

I need to run

`ResponseEntity<String> response = queryToRest.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers), String.class);`

to get my content and then convert it to a JSONObject.

How to directly have a JSONObject? Do I need to add some parameters to my RestTemplate queryToRest object?

This used to work fine under spring 1.5 but not right now with spring 2.1 (idk if it is the reason)